# Can a PDF from an Excel workbook be used to reopen entire workbook?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I use excel daily for sensitive financial information at work, and very often we have to send single sheets to owners and clients in PDF format. Now I am being told that a single excel sheet (from an entire workbook, up to 20 pages or more) can be used to convert back to Excel format which will give them access to the entire original workbook? Is this possible and if so, is there any way to prevent people from accessing other pages of the workbook that were not included in the single PDF?

To clarify, here is an example:
Excel workbook for a budget contains individual client information on separate pages. I convert ONE of those pages to PDF to send that statement to that particular client. That client can now convert the PDF back to Excel format, which saved the memory of the entire workbook and now they can see all clients statements on all other pages.

Is this correct?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The one-sheet PDF file couldn't possibly be used to reconstruct the entire workbook.

The easiest way to verify is to compare file sizes of the PDF output:
Extract one client's sheet to a new Excel file, convert to PDF, and note the size.
Then convert the entire workbook to PDF and note its size. If really, really should be bigger.